# How to check value of TextView in ListView with Espresso in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-espresso

I found a lot of similar answers on how to do it with custom id provided for ListView, like this:

```
onData(anything())
   .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listView))
   .atPosition(0)
   .onChildView(withId(R.id.numeration))
   .check(matches(withText("1")));
```

But what if my layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" ... />
    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Which ID I must provide to `.inAdapterView(withId(...))` to work with ListView? 
I tried variants like `android.R.id.list`, which gives me `No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: android:id/list` error, and `R.id.android_list`, which even don't let me run test, giving me `error: cannot find symbol variable android_list` at build time.
I stuck with this simple problem, please help! Couldn't find anything related to my case.

Comment: @user1055395 I did this intentionally, so ListView can handle cases when adapter has no data, and shows appropriate messages, instead of  me handling it

Comment: @user1055395 yes